# Random Unitary Matrices

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, random-matrices

So as I understand it, if you choose a random parameter and fill the entries of a matrix with that parameter, you get a random matrix.  I was wondering if there are some general conditions under which a matrix can be both unitary and random such that the unitarity condition is now being satisfied.

I am aware that there are already examples of random unitary matrices which can be chosen from the Haar measure, so perhaps this question is related to the concept of the Haar measure?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I understand your question as asking for a constructive method to sample uniformly from the unitary group $U(N)$ or orthogonal group $O(N)$, where "uniformly" is understood in the sense of the Haar measure. A simple method starts from an $N\times N$ matrix filled with independent Gaussian random variables [complex for $U(N)$ and real for $O(N)$]. Then orthonormalize the columns via [Gram-Schmidt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) and you're done.

For a more efficient approach, see [How to generate random matrices from the classical compact groups](https://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0609050) by Francesco Mezzadri.

The construction is implemented in Mathematica in the routines [circular unitary ensemble](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CircularUnitaryMatrixDistribution.html) for $U(N)$ and [circular real ensemble](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CircularRealMatrixDistribution.html) for $O(N)$.
<sub>Caution: the socalled [circular orthogonal ensemble](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CircularOrthogonalMatrixDistribution.html) does not sample from $O(N)$ but from the coset $U(N)/O(N)$.</sub>

Comment: That makes sense but you use independent Gaussian random variables for the matrix, I was wondering if you would take one single random variable as it were (say, all the possible numbers which can be produced by some particular random number generator) and then fill the matrix with every entry being a value which that one variable can take, I take it this is still a random matrix or to be a random matrix does every entry need to correspond to a different independent random variable?

Comment: you can use a random number generator to fill the matrix, but it is essential that this random number generator samples from a Gaussian distribution; it your random number generator samples from a uniform distribution, you will have to do some [postprocessing](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CircularOrthogonalMatrixDistribution.html) to convert that into a Gaussian.

Comment: Just checking that I understand, so in some sense it's possible to create a random matrix by just filling it with a random parameter and that will mean all the entries are independent Gaussian random variables (assuming the random parameter takes it values from a Gaussian distribution)?

Comment: Yes, indeed, that is correct.

Comment: It occurs to me that I am mainly interested in the eigenvalue statistics of many large matrices, does this mean that the entries do not need to be Gaussian random variables, as I am considering the limit of large matrix size, in which case there could be any random variables.

Comment: it all depends on what properties of the eigenvalue statistics you are interested in; for example, if you calculate the density of the eigenphases on the unit circle, it will only be uniform for the Gaussian elements, no matter how large the matrix is; on the other hand, local properties (nearest neighbor statistics) will become universal in the limit of a large matrix, but for that you don't even need to take a unitary matrix, just working with a symmetric Gaussian matrix is enough.

Comment: Yes, I was actually interested in the general histogram for the density of the eigenvalues (ie. the eigenangles) $\rho (\theta)$, not the spacing distributions.  What do you mean by 'it will only be uniform for the Gaussian elements'?

Comment: If you don’t start from Gaussian elements the eigenphases will not cover the interval (0,2pi) uniformly.

Comment: Is eigenphase same as eigenangle in this context?

Comment: yes, the eigenvalues are $e^{i\phi}$ and $\phi$ can be called the eigenphase or eigenangle, it's the same thing.

Comment: Would you mind if I clarified something, for example, say we repeatedly generate many random unitary matrices and obtain their eigenvalues, would we get a curve for the density of the eigenphases which approaches that predicted by the theoretical curve of the circulary unitary ensemble, or would that only happen in the limit of large matrix size for the matrices which are being generated?

Comment: The eigenvalue density will be uniform in the interval (0,2pi) in the limit of a large matrix size. For small matrixes there will be some deviations, At least if you take real orthogonal matrices . For complex unitary matrices the density is uniform for any matrix size.

Comment: But don't ''unitary'' matrices always have to be complex by definition?  In my case, I am generating random unitary matrices which always have complex entries by definition, so in that case the density will always be uniform independent of matrix size?

Comment: The curve I have in mind is the one in the paper by Mezzadri which you suggested, for example, so would the empirical histogram for the densities of the eigenvalues match the theoretical curve shown in Figure 1(a) for the CUE.  As I am generating random unitary matrices, I would like to say that this curve is approached regardless of matrix size as many matrices are generated repeatedly, but I notice that he is computing data not only with many matrices (10,000) but also with large matrices (size 50 x 50), so I was wondering if the large matrix size was essential to match the CUE curve?

Comment: Tom, the curve of figure 1a in the Mezzadri paper is labeled “wrong”: it is the result of an error explained in the text. The correct density is strictly uniform for any matrix size.

Comment: Yes Carlo, I have read the paper and know the curve you are referring to is incorrect, I was referring to the other uniform (ie. flat) curve which corresponds to the theoretical result and was just asking if there was any significance to the fact that he uses large matrices when generating matrices whose eigenvalue density hopefully matches the theoretical result, obviously the answer seems to be no from what you have said.

Comment: The density should be strictly flat for any N.

Answer (score 3):

The notion of random unitary matrix usually refers to the Haar measure on the group of unitary matrices; see

https://case.edu/artsci/math/esmeckes/Meckes_SAMSI_Lecture2.pdf

http://emis.ams.org/journals/EJP-ECP/article/download/2551/2345.pdf

] G. W. Anderson, A. Guionnet, and O. Zeitouni, An introduction to random matrices, Cambridge Studies in Advanced Mathematics, vol. 118, Cambridge University Press, Cambridge,
2010. MR-2760897